# How secure is encryption for passwords with crypt() in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, password-protection, crypt

I'm using `crypt()` encryption in PHP like this:

```
<?php
$password = sanitizing_func($_POST['password']);
$var = crypt($password, 'ab');
?>
```

How Secure is this?

Found a better solution here: [openwall phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Thanks to [Edward Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson)

Comment: Suggested reading - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/51403/what-should-web-programmers-know-about-cryptography, points further to informative articles, btw, aren't you sanitising user input?

Comment: Oh yes I do that, this was an example, I don't put the POST['password'] as it is. I'm going to read you advised link

Comment: Thy shalt not trust user input!

Comment: Yes I know I got FatFree framework that take care of all those thing

Comment: @Kumar, why should he sanitize it? It'll be encrypted anyway.

Comment: @buddy forgive me for being paranoid, but I prefer not to blindly trust user input, I do not want for the day when user posts something that just breaks my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's less secure than if you just use `crypt` the way it was designed, with the password as the first argument and the salt as the second.

Now you're encrypting known plaintext using the user's password as the salt.  If your system uses an MD5 `crypt`, then you've just limited the salt space to 12 characters, so you're truncating the space of users passwords to twelve characters.  Worse still, my system requires me to use a prefix on the salt in order to specify my crypt, or else I get old school `crypt`, meaning you have **two characters** for the salt.  So you've limited the possible length of a users password to two characters.  Plus there's no point in even running `crypt` at this point, you might as well just store their two character password, since the salt is prefixed to the ciphertext so that subsequent calls to `crypt` can pass the same salt.

Also, you're limiting the character space of the password by using it in the salt, since the character space of the salt is limited to A-Z, a-z, 0-9, ".", "/".  Even if you switch the arguments around from your code example, you're using the same salt data for every call.  This means that every password has the same salt.  So if your password table is exposed, it becomes less computationally expensive to crack using a dictionary attack.

In other words, swapping the password and salt arguments is a fatal mistake.

Finally, there's simply no reason to call crypt twice.  If you want better encryption, use a better algorithm, don't call it more frequently.  For example, if you're using a DES crypt, then it's still an ancient algorithm no matter how many times you call it.  (I also seem to remember reading that multiple passes of an algorithm may inadvertently produce weakened ciphertext.  But I don't have Schneier in front of me.)

What you want to do is the industry standard:  use a strong crypt, pass the password as the first argument and *random salt data* in as the second argument and make sure that you're passing the maximum allowable number of bytes in for the salt.

Comment: Ok now i'm a bit lost on the random salt: how do I get it back?
I mean how do I check it in login if the salt is random? Isn't better a constant there?
<?php
$var = crypt($_POST['password'], CONSTANT);
?>

Comment: No.  Your salt is prepended the the ciphertext to get the return value.  For old school DES crypt, it will be the first two characters.  So you pick two random characters, and cryptedPass = crypt(PASSWORD, "ab"); where "ab" is the random salt.  The cryptedPass return value will be prefixed with ab, the random salt.  So you store the cryptedPass result.  Then when the user types their password again, you fetch the cryptedPass that you stored so that you can get the salt you used originally.  Then run crypt() again with their input and that original salt, comparing to cryptedPass.

Comment: Thanks Edward, just the password that comes up is kinda short, i was used to very long strings with md5 and friends ( i know how unsecure they are with raimbow tables)... well i wanna trust crypt

Comment: If you look at http://www.php.net/crypt it discusses how to (generally) get a different algorithm by passing a different prefix to salt.  If you use $1$ as the first three characters of your salt, you'll get MD5, for example.

Comment: So just the crypt(), as it is, it's really secure isn't it?
I really hope so. Thanks

Comment: It's hard for me (or anyone else) to tell you what would be "strong enough" for your application.  A password to a site that hosts a list of the songs I recently listened to has very different security requirements than my banking statements than does some coded communications to a spy in a hostile territory.  That said, DES is considered exceptionally weak and MD5 is also considered weak.  You could use SHA-256.  You could also look at http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ which is an implementation of bcrypt - http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: Thanks, this [link](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) did it, I am gonna sleep better at night, I hope.